# I am using CSS to hide radio buttons, but I would like to display them on one page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, qualtrics

On Qualtrics, I have entered the following CSS to hide radio buttons in the entire survey:

```
input[type=radio]{
visibility: hidden;  
}
```

However I would like them displayed for one page. I can only use javascript to do this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add the jQuery library.  Qualtrics uses prototype.js and you can use that.  Just add the following JavaScript to the first question on your page:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $$('input[type=radio]').each(function(obj) {
        obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
    });
});
```

The code finds all the radio radio buttons on the page and changes them to visible.

Comment: Hmm for some reason this doesn't work, do you have any ideas?

Comment: It works for me. Example here: https://marketinview.qualtrics.com/WRQualtricsSurveyEngine/?SID=SV_d4J9DjCtDmQ2lGB&SVID=&Preview=Block&ID=BL_4Gv8jqmMgMjYd3n&Q_DONT_SAVE=1

Check to make sure question JS is exactly as shown above.

Comment: Super! I just had to delete the bit that was there automatically. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to accomplish this is to create a seperate class in your CSS:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

And then add or remove that class as needed.  For example:

```
document.getElementById("special-checkbox").classList.add('hidden');
```

If you absolutely must use the declaration `input[type=radio]` eactly as in your problem, then you can override this using the same technique:

```
input[type=radio].shown {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And you'll use javascript just like above to add the `shown` class to those items that are being unhidden.  Because this qualifier is more specific than your general selector, it will take precedence.

**Edit**

Something I missed.  If you want all of the radio buttons on a particular page to be hidden or shown, you could attach a class to any common ancestor in the DOM, and then use cascading.  For example, you could attach the class `show-radio` to some DIV tag higher in the hierarchy (using the technique above), and then the following rule would cascade your intentions to all of the radio inputs.

```
show-radio input[type=radio] {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This is nice because you only have to set a class once, instead of once for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do:

$('input[type=radio]').css({visibility: 'visible'});

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work... can you think of any potential reasons why?

Comment: I don't know Qualtrics but the other people said that it uses Prototype already, so jQuery won't work in this case.